# Custom error pages are not showing

Tags: cakephp, error-handling

I have a custom error page for 500 Server Errors in CakePHP 3.

My `src\Template\Layout\error.ctp` template file has been adjusted to have my default error template in it. And then I've also updated my view file at `src\Template\Error\error500.ctp`. I even added this line, `$this->layout = 'error';` as described in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#exception-renderer).

This is what my error view looks like:

```
<?php
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Error\Debugger;

$this->layout = 'error';
$this->Html->addCrumb('Error');
?>

<section class="content">
    <div class="error-page">
        <h2 class="headline text-red">500</h2>
        <div class="error-content">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-warning text-red"></i> Oops! Something went wrong.</h3>
            <p>
                We will work on fixing that right away.
                Meanwhile, you may <a href="../../index.html">return to dashboard</a> or try using the search form.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

However, it still shows the default CakePHP error page.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn off the debug in `app.php` like

```
'debug' => false
```

As it written in cookbook

> Each framework layer exception has its own view file located in the core templates but you really don’t need to bother customizing them as they are used only during development. **With debug turned off all framework layer exceptions are converted to InternalErrorException**

For detailed info about ExceptionRenderer visit [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#exception-renderer)